# how to access user principal in tomcat custom valve

Tags: java, tomcat

Please help me on the below item:

1. Where exactly custom valve used instead of a filter?
2. In our application, I have created tomcat 9 custom valve and trying to access user principal from the valve. but in the valve, it returns null. but we are able to access from the filter. we have used form-based authentication.
3. User Principal will be available in Custom valve or is it available on in fliter?

Code snippet is provided below:

```
public class ContextInitializerValve extends ValveBase {



public ContextInitializerValve() {
    System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
}

@Override
public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {


        System.out.println("======================custom valve==============================");
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have created a Valve instead of a filter, without knowing what it's good for? Let's start by figuring out the usecase you're implementing. If you let us know more about it, we can point you to a proper implementation of it.

Comment: I am trying to know where Valve we can use instead of a filter, where the use case is I am trying to put some values in the thread local so that all the data is available in the thread so when we want we can get instead querying from LDAP multiple times ( my question is through filter also we can do that but in code where I am looking which someone has written already they have added in custom Valve)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of valves as the equivalent for filters, but server-side, not on the application side. E.g. you'd deploy a valve to the server, and typically can't hot-deploy new versions of it without restarting the server. You could redeploy a filter by redeploying your application that contains the filter.

Both Valves and Filters are order-sensitive: When you use Valves (tomcat uses them for server-side authentication) and you are sure that a user is authenticated, but you don't get the principal, your valve seems to be running before tomcat's authentication valve. You can either make sure to have your valve configured in the correct order, or move the implementation to a filter, because filters always run *after* all valves have been running.

In principle, they're very similar. Filters are defined by the servlet spec, while Valves (being part of the server implementation) are defined by Tomcat.